# Ошибка: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'

Tags: python, бот

Скопировал код из интернета, хотел попробовать сделать кнопочки, но столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\мой_юзер\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\hi.py", line 3, in <module>
    from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_components'
```

Вроде, пишет про то, что нет модуля discord_components, но как тогда у других работает этот код? Вот этот код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/', intents = discord.Intents.all())
TOKEN = 'секретик'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(client)
    print('Bot connected')


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send(
        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Вы точно хотите перевевсти деньги?'),
        components = [
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.green, label = 'Да'),
            Button(style = ButtonStyle.red, label = 'Нет')
        ])
    responce = await client.wait_for('button_click', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if responce.component.label == 'Да':
        await responce.respond(content = 'Деньги успешно переведены!')
    else:
        await responce.respond(content = 'Вы отменили перевод.')
```

Comment: Про кнопочки и другие UI-элементы можете почитать здесь: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/ui_elements.md#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: - "как тогда у других работает этот код? " - Наверное, у других "module named 'discord_components'" установлен. Попробуйте "pip install discord_components"